# Laravel 5.1 SSL in Localhost

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, localhost

I'm moving my working project to laravel. In order process i'm using SSL Certificate.

cart, orderAddress, orderPayment, orderResults are four steps of Order Process.

My first question is "What is best practice to disable ssl certificate in localhost ?"

If mine is good (in below) "How can i shorten this code ?" Because i'm repeating myself that's why i didn't like.

```
/**
 * Disable ssl in Localhost
 */
if (App::environment('local')) {
    Route::get('/cart', [
        'uses' => 'CartController@index',
        'as'   => 'cart',
    ]);
    Route::get('/orderAddress', [
        'uses' => 'AddressController@orderIndex',
        'as'   => 'orderAddress',
    ]);
    Route::get('/orderPayment', [
        'uses' => 'PaymentController@orderPayment',
        'as'   => 'orderPayment',
    ]);
    Route::get('/orderResult', [
        'uses' => 'OrderController@orderResult',
        'as'   => 'orderResult',
    ]);
} else {
/**
 * SSL PAGES
 */
Route::group(['before' => 'force.ssl'], function()
{
    Route::get('/cart', [
        'uses' => 'CartController@index',
        'as'   => 'cart',
    ]);
    Route::get('/orderAddress', [
        'uses' => 'AddressController@orderIndex',
        'as'   => 'orderAddress',
    ]);
    Route::get('/orderPayment', [
        'uses' => 'PaymentController@orderPayment',
        'as'   => 'orderPayment',
    ]);
    Route::get('/orderResult', [
        'uses' => 'OrderController@orderResult',
        'as'   => 'orderResult',
    ]);
});

Route::filter('force.ssl', function()
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }

});
```

Comment: You can put your local test in the filter and always apply it.

Comment: _“My first question is What is best practice to disable ssl certificate in localhost ?”_ – is that the _right_ question to begin with? I’d rather say, issue a self-signed certificate for your local test domain, and get your test browser(s) to accept it once. Mimicking your production setup as closely as possible in your dev setup is always a good idea.

Comment: @CBroe you're right. But i have e-commerce system now. And i'm using. Now i decided to convert to a laravel project. I have no much time. And i have no idea about self-signed certificate on test domain. Can you share me a link i want to learn about it. Thank you.

Comment: That should be easy enough to research, https://www.google.com/search?q=create+self-signed+ssl+certificate And how to set up your local server for SSL/HTTPS as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a middle ware like:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App;
use Redirect;

class UseSSL
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if( App::environment('local') ){
            return Redirect::secure($request->path());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then register it in `Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'use.ssl' => UseSSL::class
];
```

Now you can say

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'use.ssl'], function () {

    Route::get('/cart', [
        'uses' => 'CartController@index',
        'as'   => 'cart',
    ]);
    Route::get('/orderAddress', [
        'uses' => 'AddressController@orderIndex',
        'as'   => 'orderAddress',
    ]);
    Route::get('/orderPayment', [
        'uses' => 'PaymentController@orderPayment',
        'as'   => 'orderPayment',
    ]);
    Route::get('/orderResult', [
        'uses' => 'OrderController@orderResult',
        'as'   => 'orderResult',
    ]);
});
```

Let me know if it works! :)

Comment: it works perfectly. There exists small problems. I edited your post. If you confirm it works very well.